# One of my questions of stackoverflow was closed - would it be more appropriate here?

Tags: discussion, topicality

I asked a [question about resource allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653179/looking-for-an-algorithm-to-allocate-climbing-hold-colors-to-wall-sectors) (kind of) on stackoverflow which was closed as off-topic. My problem is that I need to allocate climbing hold colors to wall sectors, while some rules have to be followed.

My new question is: is this a better place to ask it? If I can post it here, I'll delete it at stackoverflow and re-phrase it for scicomp.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it could work. Send it on over.